# Adding a constructor's properties to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to add a Person which has been defined within a constructor to an ArrayList so that I can then call a method which is in another class. I'm having issues with actually adding a `Person` to the ArrayList however. Here is what I have so far:

**GrownUp class updated**

```
public class GrownUp extends Person
{
    ArrayList<Person> people;



GrownUp(int age, String name)  
{
    super(age, name);
    this.people = new ArrayList<>();        
    name = "Bill";
    age = 36;        
}  

public ArrayList<Person> getGrownUp()
{
   return people;
}

public void setGrownUp(int age, String name)
{
    //how to add a GrownUp? 
}
```

So what needs to be done is:

- Add `Person` who has been defined as "Bill" aged 36 to ArrayList `people`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

I previously asked a question similar ot this but was not clear in what I was asking so I've changed my question so that hopefully it makes more sense in what I'm trying to achieve. I've added a get method but I can't figure out how to do the set method. how would I relate the `Person` constructor to the ArrayList to add a person into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a bit strange to have the people array within the GrownUp class. Try to map it to the real world. Would it make sense to have people within a GrownUp? I would rather have that array outside and do this:

```
List<People> people = new ArrayList<>();
people.add(new GrownUp(25, "Alice"));
people.add(new GrownUp(36, "Bill"));
people.add(new Child(5, "Nina"));
```

The GrownUp class would then look like this:

```
public class GrownUp extends Person {

    public GrownUp(int age, String name) {
        super(age, name)
    }
}
```

I guess you are planning to add more properties that is specific to the GrownUp class, like `Optional<DriversLicense> getDriversLicense()` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, if I was to say call a method on that GrownUp, how would I do this if the method was called `eat()`?

Comment: If all persons (including children) were to eat:
`people.stream().foreach(person -> person.eat());`

If just GrownUps were to eat:
`people.stream().filter(person -> person instanceof GrownUp.class).foreach(grownUp -> grownUp.eat());`

Comment: To get all driversLicences.
`List<DriversLicense> driversLicenses = people.stream().filter(person -> person instanceof GrownUp.class).foreach(grownUp -> ((GrownUp) grownUp).getDriversLicense()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: It looks a bit messy here, but if you break lines before the dots it should look better. You can of course also use traditional for-loops instead of the stream API for this.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you.

```
public void setGrownUp(int age, String name)
{
people.add(new GrownUp(age,name));
}
```